# cross join/merge dataframe1 to create dataframe2 of combinations based on column in dataframe1

Tags: python, join, pandas, merge, combinations

This is a similar question to: [cross join/merge to create dataframe of combinations (order doesn't matter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780710/cross-join-merge-to-create-dataframe-of-combinations-order-doesnt-matter)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'zone2': ['IL', 'IL-1', 'IL-3', 'IL'], 
                   'city': ['Chicago', 'St.Louis', 'Monmouth', 'DesMoines'],
                   'zone1': ['Mid', 'Mid', 'Mid', 'Mid']})
```

I want to create second dataframe of all combinations of column=city.

This is the way I do it but there must be an efficient way to do this in fewer steps.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.combinations(list(df['city']), 2)))
df2.columns = ['city_1', 'city_2']
df2 = df2.merge(df, left_on='city_1', right_on='city').merge(df, left_on='city_2', right_on='city', suffixes=('_x', '_y'))
df2.drop(['city_x', 'city_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)
>>> df2

     city_1     city_2 zone1_x zone2_x zone1_y zone2_y
0   Chicago   St.Louis     Mid      IL     Mid    IL-1
1   Chicago   Monmouth     Mid      IL     Mid    IL-3
2  St.Louis   Monmouth     Mid    IL-1     Mid    IL-3
3   Chicago  DesMoines     Mid      IL     Mid      IL
4  St.Louis  DesMoines     Mid    IL-1     Mid      IL
5  Monmouth  DesMoines     Mid    IL-3     Mid      IL>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import combinations

>>> pd.DataFrame(
        (pair[0] + pair[1] 
         for pair in (df.loc[df.city == a].values.tolist() + 
                      df.loc[df.city == b].values.tolist() 
         for a, b in combinations(df.city.unique(), 2))), 
         columns=df.columns.tolist()+[c+"_2" for c in df])
       city zone1 zone2     city_2 zone1_2 zone2_2
0   Chicago   Mid    IL   St.Louis     Mid    IL-1
1   Chicago   Mid    IL   Monmouth     Mid    IL-3
2   Chicago   Mid    IL  DesMoines     Mid      IL
3  St.Louis   Mid  IL-1   Monmouth     Mid    IL-3
4  St.Louis   Mid  IL-1  DesMoines     Mid      IL
5  Monmouth   Mid  IL-3  DesMoines     Mid      IL
```

You could also try a variant of this:

```
pairs = ((a, b) for a, b in combinations(df.index, 2))

>>> pd.DataFrame({
        'city_1': df.ix[p[0], 'city'],
        'city_2': df.ix[p[1], 'city'],
        'zone1_1': df.ix[p[0], 'zone1'],
        'zone1_2': df.ix[p[1], 'zone1'],
        'zone2_1': df.ix[p[0], 'zone2'],
        'zone2_2': df.ix[p[1], 'zone2']} for p in pairs)

     city_1     city_2 zone1_1 zone1_2 zone2_1 zone2_2
0   Chicago   St.Louis     Mid     Mid      IL    IL-1
1   Chicago   Monmouth     Mid     Mid      IL    IL-3
2   Chicago  DesMoines     Mid     Mid      IL      IL
3  St.Louis   Monmouth     Mid     Mid    IL-1    IL-3
4  St.Louis  DesMoines     Mid     Mid    IL-1      IL
5  Monmouth  DesMoines     Mid     Mid    IL-3      IL
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Wow, that is fairly complicated. I'm surprised that there isn't a built in way to achieve the frame I want.